# Why is it a misconception and not a misconcept?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

A [misconception](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misconception) is:

> - a mistaken thought, idea, or notion; a misunderstanding: *had many misconceptions about the new tax program.* (AHD)

- Despite the different nuances in meaning the above definition could well refer both to a mistaken [concept](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concept)  (a general idea or understanding of something) and a mistaken  [conception](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conception) (something conceived in the mind or believed by a group of people; a concept, thought, or belief).

According to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=misconception&allowed_in_frame=0) the term *misconception* dates back to:

> - 1660s, from mis- (1) + conception.

By that time both [concept](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=concept&allowed_in_frame=0) (1550s) and [conception](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=conception&allowed_in_frame=0) (meaning "that which is conceived in the mind" is from 1520s) had been used by more than a century, but conception somehow was chosen to indicate a wrong idea/notion.

Question:

Is there a reason for the fact that *misconception* became a commonly accepted term while *misconcept* did not. Could it be because conception had  been  a more popular term in the past for its original meaning *"in the womb sense (also with reference to Conception Day in the Church calendar)"*?

Comment: If _misconcept_ breaks the rules of English as @GregLee suggests, this has never stopped English speakers from doing that many times in the past.  But _misconceive_ and _misconception_ are clearly the winners in everyday usage  compared  to _misconcept_.  Perhaps because _misconcept_  is (or would be) neither clearly a noun or a verb.  Certitude trumps ambiguity most times outside of poetry.  But _'misconcept'_ as a word for a wrong-headed 'Concept' or 'general conception' (in the philosophical sense) is still attractive.

Answer (score 1):

"misconcept" is not a word.  The prefix "mis-" can be added to verbs, but not to nouns, and "concept" is a noun.

Most derivational affixes are restricted to be added to just one part of speech.  In the form "misconception", the prefix "mis-" is not added to the noun "conception", but rather to the verb "conceive", then the derived verb "misconceive" is converted to a noun by addition of the "-ion" suffix.  The morphological structure of "misconception" is [N [V mis [V conceive] ] ion].

Comment: Doesn't  'concept' derive from 'conceive as conception?  : * from concep-, past participle stem of concipere "to take in" (see conceive).*

Comment: @Josh61 "Concept" and "conception" are both derived from "conceive".

Comment: That is what I am telling you, so form *misconceive* we could both have *misconception* and *misconcept*.

Comment: @Josh61 You mean that since "concept" is from "conceive", it should be possible to derive "misconcept" from "misconceive"?  Well, apparently not.  Though in defense of this, we do have both "believe"->"belief" and "disbelieve"->"disbelief".

Comment: yes, that's my point, and I think that 'conception' was sort of preferred word for its 'religious' usage. I probably should ask that on the linguistic site.

Answer (score 1):

*conception* and *misconception* refer to the **act** of conceiving, or creating, a concept (idea).

*concept* refers to the **idea** that this act conceives, that is, to the result of the action of *conception*.

*misconcept* would refer to what? An idea that is misconceived, perhaps? That is, if you coin this word it could refer to the idea that is the result of *misconception*.

It is true that we sometimes think of *misconception* as the idea that results from the act (anidea that is poorly or incorrectly conceived). But this is, IMO, an abbreviation.  Possibly it happens because, unlike the case for *conception* and *concept*, we have only one word (no *misconcept*). (But see also next, about negative statements about conception, which might apply here as well, as misconception is closely related to a negation of conception.)

It is also true that we sometimes think of *conception* as the idea that results from the act. But, again, IMO this is an abbreviation. And I think that this use is especially for negative and interrogative sentences: *You have no conception what she is talking about.* Really, such uses are still better thought of as referring to the act of conceiving, IMO.

(And yes, I realize that I'm giving my feeling for what these terms mean, and that this apparently differs from the definition of *misconception* provided by the OP from the Free Dictionary etc.  Downvote, if you like.)

Comment: There are different subtle nuances that make the two terms look different, but they are used also as synonyms as dictionaries suggest. I think my issue is more an etymological one rather than a current usage one.